# Unable to fetch user's profile picture from facebook. Please see details

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to fetch user's facebook profile picture but I am unable to do so with my code. However, I have succeeded in fetching user's name, email & id.

Here is what I have done to fetch user's name, email, id & profile picture:

```
public class SignUpScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button facebookLoginButton;
    CircleImageView mProfileImage;
    TextView mUsername, mEmailID;
    Profile mFbProfile;
    ParseUser user;
    public String name, email, userID;
    public static final List<String> mPermissions = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("public_profile");
        add("email");
    }};

    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    public SignUpScreen() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_sign_up_screen);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Paci.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);

        mProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image);
        mUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        mEmailID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutUser);

        mFbProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        facebookLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
        facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(SignUpScreen.this, mPermissions, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {

                        if (user == null) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                        } else if (user.isNew()) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                            getUserDetailsFromFacebook();
                            final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                            handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    saveNewUser();
                                }
                            }, 5000);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.signup_using_email_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SignUpScreen.this);
                        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        dialog.setCancelable(true);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_for_email_signin);

                        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.email_signup_btn);
                        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                                handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }, 200);
                            }
                        });

                        dialog.show();
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.already_user).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(SignUpScreen.this, LoginScreen.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void saveNewUser() {
        user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword("hidden");

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "SignUp Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "SignUp Unsuccesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("error when signingup", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });

                user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "error saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("error when saving", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void getUserDetailsFromFacebook() {

        final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        Log.d("response", "response" + object.toString());
                        //Intent profileIntent = new Intent(SignUpScreen.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        //Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        try {
                            name = response.getJSONObject().getString("name");
                            mUsername.setText(name);
                            email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                            mEmailID.setText(email);
                            userID = response.getJSONObject().getString("id");

                            //b.putString("userName", name);
                            //b.putString("userEmail", email);

                            //profileIntent.putExtras(b);
                            //startActivity(profileIntent);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "name, email, id");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }

    class ProfilePicAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        Bitmap bmp = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... id) {

            String imageURL;
            Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "Loading picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ id +"/picture?type=small";
            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "Loading picture failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Loading picture failed", e.toString());

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            mProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

**This code is not fetching the user's profile picture.**

Please let me know what is wrong!

I'm using Facebook API for first time, so please cooperate if there are some silly errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? In which line of your code? The login does work?

Comment: @Paul everything works. just profile pic is not coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**add** `new ProfilePicAsync().execute(userID);`

**below**

```
userID = response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
```

**in**

```
 private void getUserDetailsFromFacebook() {...}
```

and replace `imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ id +"/picture?type=small";` with

```
imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ id[0].toString +"/picture?type=small";
```

Comment: after running this code, I got: `01-01 17:26:05.257 18640-18678/com.abc.xyz D/Loading picture failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/[Ljava.lang.String;@2cfd018/picture?type=small
`

Comment: @HammadNasir: try new ProfilePicAsync().execute(userID.toString); and  add Log.d("fb id", id); in doInbackground to see value in id

Comment: the problem is that I'm fetching the 'id' in `getUserDetailsFromFacebook()`. how can I get same 'id' in `doInBackground()`?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. Thanks to [user3069305](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3069305/user3069305)

I did this in `doInBackground()`:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String imageURL;
            String id = userID;
            imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ id +"/picture?type=small";
            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Loading picture failed", e.toString());

            }

            return null;
        }
```